# How to save time along with user enter date in timestamp in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

Using timestamp for date and time saving.User enter only date, I want that before save time also append along with this.

By default timestamp add time 00:00:00

```
["end_date", "2015-11-30 00:00:00"]
```

I want that I add time 23:59:59 and it looks like this

```
["end_date", "2015-11-30 23:59:59"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pry(main)> Date.parse("2015-11-30").beginning_of_day.to_s
=> "2015-11-30 00:00:00 -0800"

pry(main)> Date.parse("2015-11-30").end_of_day.to_s
=> "2015-11-30 23:59:59 -0800"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in model

```
before_create :set_end_date

def set_end_date
   "#{self.end_date} 00:00:00".to_time.to_formatted_s(:db)
end
```

You will get response like this: `2015-11-30 00:00:00`

If you add 23:00:00 then use this:

```
"#{self.end_date} 23:59:59".to_time.to_formatted_s(:db)
```

then you will get response like: `2015-11-30 23:59:59`

For more formatting, you should refer this [document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html).